# Split strings to extract partial filename

Tags: regex, powershell, split

Can you please suggest me on how to get the output using split or any other commands using PowerShell.

```
*string = "version(2.3.4)_stack_over_flow.zip"
```

required output : `"stack_over_flow"*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
$string = "version(2.3.4)_stack_over_flow.zip"
$a,$b= $string.split(').')
$b[2].Substring(1)
stack_over_flow
```

OR as per @Drew's comments you could shorten above as:

```
($string.Split(').'))[3].substring(1)
```

OR by using `match` regex try following:

```
$found = $string -match '.*\)_([^.]*).*'
if ($found) {
     $val = $matches[1]
}
$val
stack_over_flow
```

Comment: You could also replace lines 2 & 3 with `($string.Split(').'))[3].substring(1)`